# What did Shouya want to say to Shouko?

Tags: koe-no-katachi

[image: hands]

During this scene, Shouya tells something like "*Ore wa saa...*" to Shouko, which I believe translates to something which the subtitles show as well, "You see, I...". But while completing the sentence, he falls, which leads to him being unable to complete it.

Nowhere in the movie further, is mentioned about this thing (at least I haven't noticed it :B).

Is there any sort of official statement on what he might've wanted to say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the manga version, Ishida said,

> **"It's cold... and it's warm"**

The sentence didn't look fit with what Ishida said before. Rephrasing it a little bit,

> **"By the way/You see, I... feel cold and warm"**

Well, my thought about what the meaning of these words are:

- "It's cold" refers to the cold of the river
- "it's warm" refers to the blood starting to surround his body when he's in the river. [The average temperature of blood](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS763US763&q=average%20temperature%20of%20blood&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTgfnJu-bXAhXPRN8KHYh-BqUQvwUIJigA&biw=1868&bih=1109) is pretty high, and when it's escaping your body that quickly you can tend to feel the warmth before it has time to cool off. You can see in the frame where Ishida mentions "It's Warm" is the same frame where he begins to bleed out. Same goes for in the movie, its voiced over as soon as he begins bleeding out as well.

**Volume 6, chapter 43: page 15, 16, 17**

[image: "by the way,..."]

[image: "it's warm... it's cold"]

Comment: Argh, there goes my shipping hope. ;-; I thought he was going to confess or something :P. Anyways, going to wait a few hours more before accepting to see any other answer comes up! Anyways, thank you for the answer \o/

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help (y) @SaitamaSama

Comment: I used to think he said "I love you" but then, I thought about when he looked at her ear and then I thought he said "I'm sorry" But I guess my ship failed because he was really talking about temperatures.